# Javascript function Only works once (PHP file)

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

```
<table class="blueTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>kopieer</th>
        <th>Dag</th>
        <th>Openings tijd</th>
        <th>Sluitings tijd</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $dagen = array("Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag");
    
    foreach ($dagen as $dag) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="<?= $dag; ?>_kopie" id="<?= $dag; ?>_kopie" onchange="kopie('<?= $dag; ?>');">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php foreach ($dagen as $day) { ?>
                        <option value="<?= $day; ?>"><?= $day; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><b><?= $dag; ?></b></td>
            <td>
                <?php GetalDropDown(0, 23, $dag . "_open_uur", @$_POST[$dag . "_open_uur"], $_POST[$dag . "_open_uur"], TRUE); ?>:
                <?php GetalDropDown(0, 59, $dag . "_open_minuut", @$_POST[$dag . "_open_minuut"], $_POST[$dag . "_open_minuut"], TRUE); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php GetalDropDown(0, 23, $dag . "_sluit_uur", @$_POST[$dag . "_sluit_uur"], $_POST[$dag . "_sluit_uur"], TRUE); ?>:
                <?php GetalDropDown(0, 59, $dag . "_sluit_minuut", @$_POST[$dag . "_sluit_minuut"], $_POST[$dag . "_sluit_minuut"], TRUE); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script language="JavaScript">

    function kopie(dag) {
        kopie = dag + "_kopie";
        nieuwe_dag_waarden = document.getElementById(kopie).value;

        array = ["_open_uur", "_open_minuut", "_sluit_uur", "_sluit_minuut"];

        for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            oud = dag + array[index];
            nieuw = nieuwe_dag_waarden + array[index];
            document.getElementById(oud).value = document.getElementById(nieuw).value;
        }

        document.getElementById(kopie).value = "";
    }

</script>
```

The first time i change one of the onchange dropdowns it works fine but after that the function doesnt fire at all anymore on any of the onchange dropdowns.

the function changes the openings and sluitings tijd dropdowns to the values of whatever day you chose.

if you choose monday for tuesday, tuesday openings en closing values willl change to the values of monday.

```
function GetalDropDown($start, $eind, $naam, $selected, $current_value, $metnul=true) {

    echo "\t<select name=\"$naam\" id=\"$naam\" style=\"WIDTH: 65px\"\">\n";
    if ($selected == "") {
         $selected = $current_value;
    }

    echo "\t<option value=\"\" > - </option>\n";
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $eind; $i++) {
        $waarde = $i;
                   
        if (strlen($waarde) == 1 && $metnul == true) {
            $waarde = "0" . $waarde;
        }

        if (strcmp($waarde, $selected) == 0) {
            $aan = "SELECTED";
        } else {
            $aan = "";
        }
        echo "\t<option value=\"" . $waarde . "\" $aan>" . $waarde . "</option>\n";
    }

    echo "</select>\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the PHP code with the HTML output and ideally create a [mre]?

Comment: If you could share the function definition for `GetalDropDown`, it would greatly help assist debugging efforts here. Also, remove the `@` error suppression operator. That's stopping you from seeing what might be wrong.

Comment: @CoryCollier i removed the @ but nothing changed. i edited the post and added the getaldropdown function

Comment: Quick note here: you're using _POST values as inputs into your `GetalDropDown` function. Changing the value of the select input executes javascript, but doesn't provide any _POST values. I'm not sure why _POST is being used here?

Comment: $selected and $current_value inside the getaldropdown function basiclly do the same thing, they remember the last selected value. so if you post the form and you stay on the same page, the right number is still selected. why it is double i dont know, i didnt make the function. maybe bc if the POST was empty but the database field was filled, it is still remembered but i dont use the database.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to change the kopie function a bit. i still dont know what was the the problem but what i noticed is that the variables caused issues.

new kopie function:

```
function kopie(dag) {
     document.getElementById(dag + "_open_uur").value =  document.getElementById(document.getElementById(dag + "_kopie").value + "_open_uur").value;
     document.getElementById(dag + "_open_minuut").value =  document.getElementById(document.getElementById(dag + "_kopie").value + "_open_minuut").value;
     document.getElementById(dag + "_sluit_uur").value =  document.getElementById(document.getElementById(dag + "_kopie").value + "_sluit_uur").value;
     document.getElementById(dag + "_sluit_minuut").value =  document.getElementById(document.getElementById(dag + "_kopie").value + "_sluit_minuut").value;

     document.getElementById(dag + "_kopie").value = "";
}
```